# R: Dplyr Equivalent of "Fuzzy Join"

Tags: r, join, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. Does anyone know that if the "dplyr" library has any way of running "fuzzy joins"?

For instance, supposed I have the following data:

In the R programming language, I am interested in performing a "fuzzy join" and passing this through a SQL Connection:

```
library(dplyr)


table_1 = data.frame(id1 = c("123 A", "123BB", "12 5", "12--5"), id2 = c("11", "12", "14", "13"),
date_1 = c("2010-01-31","2010-01-31", "2015-01-31", "2018-01-31" ))

table_1$id1 = as.factor(table_1$id1)
table_1$id2 = as.factor(table_1$id2)
table_1$date_1 = as.factor(table_1$date_1)

table_2 = data.frame(id1 = c("0123", "1233", "125  .", "125_"), id2 = c("111", "112", "14", "113"),
date_2 = c("2009-01-31","2010-01-31", "2010-01-31", "2010-01-31" ),
date_3 = c("2011-01-31","2010-01-31", "2020-01-31", "2020-01-31" ))


table_2$id1 = as.factor(table_2$id1)
table_2$id2 = as.factor(table_2$id2)
table_2$date_2 = as.factor(table_2$date_2)
table_2$date_3 = as.factor(table_2$date_3)
```

**My Question:** Does anyone know if the code below would have an equivalent with "dbplyr" (instead of with "fuzzyjoin")?

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

join = stringdist_inner_join(table_1, table_2, by = "id2", max_dist = 2) %>%
  filter(date_1 >= date_2, date_1 <= date_3)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a `full-join` and calculate then string editting distance of your choice. You need more than the `dplyr` package though as you probably do not want do implement the calculation of string editting distance from scratch. The package of choice probably would be `stringdist` and actually this is what the `fuzzyjoin` function you are asking about uses under the hood.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringdist)

# generate all possible combinations with dplyr
dplyr::full_join(table_1, table_2, by = character()) %>%
    # calculate string editting distance and use to filter
    dplyr::filter(stringdist::stringdist(id2.x, id2.y) < 3)
```

I have no idea if this will be more or less performant then the `fuzzyjoin` implementation. If you want to speed up the process or are facing RAM problems, you could segment table_1 and full join on each segment the entire table_2, run the calculation (on multiple cores i.e.) and bind the result.