# "fuzzy" inner_join in dplyr to keep both rows that do AND not exactly match

Tags: r, dplyr, inner-join, fuzzyjoin

I am working with two datasets that I would like to join based not **exact** matches between them, but rather approximate matches. My question is similar to this [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70343975/r-dplyr-equivalent-of-fuzzy-join).

Here are examples of what my two dataframes look like.

`df1` is this one:

```
 x
 4.8
 12  
 4  
 3.5
 12.5
 18
```

`df2` is this one:

```
 x     y
 4.8   6.6
 12    1  
 4.5   1  
 3.5   0.5
 13    1.8
 15    2
```

I am currently using `inner_join(df1, df2, by=c("x")` to join the two together.

This gives me:

```
 x     y
 4.8   6.6
 12    1
 3.5   0.5
```

**However, what I really want to do is join the two `df`s based on these conditions:**

1. any exact matches are joined first (exactly like how `inner_join()` currently works)
2. BUT, if there are no exact matches, then join to any match ± 0.5

The kind of output I am trying to get would look like this:

```
 x     y
 4.8   6.6
 12    1
 4     1    #the y value is from x=4.5 in df1
 4     0.5  #the y value is from x=3.5 in df1
 3.5   0.5
 12.5  1    #the y value is from x=12 in df1
 12.5  1.8  #the y value is from x=13 in df1
```

I typically work in `dplyr`, so a `dplyr` solution would be appreciated. But, I am also open to other suggestions because I don't know if `dplyr` will be flexible enough to do a "fuzzy" join.

(I am aware of the `fuzzyjoin` package, but it doesn't seem to get at exactly what I am trying to do here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution, with no `join`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  rename(x1 = x) %>%
  crossing(df2) %>%
  mutate(diff = abs(x1-x)) %>% 
  filter(diff <= 0.5) %>% 
  group_by(x1) %>% 
  mutate(aux = any(diff == 0)) %>% 
  filter(aux*(diff == 0) | !aux) %>% 
  select(-diff, -aux) %>% 
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>      x1     x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   3.5   3.5   0.5
#> 2   4     3.5   0.5
#> 3   4     4.5   1  
#> 4   4.8   4.8   6.6
#> 5  12    12     1  
#> 6  12.5  12     1  
#> 7  12.5  13     1.8
```

Comment: This does it nearly perfectly! One part is missing: how would you recommend dealing with perfect matches? I figure I could add an `if` `else` sort of statement and further `filter()` for the perfect matches, but I am wondering if there is a more straightforward way.

Comment: You are welcome! I do not quite understand you question, as `abs(x1 - x) <= 0.5` also includes the cases of perfect matches, as `x1 == x` satisfies the condition `abs(x1 - x) <= 0.5`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: So, if we look at `x1==4.8` it is there twice because it is close to `x==4.5` and `x==4.8`, but is it possible for those cases (exact matches) to only be in the `df` once, despite that they might have non-exact matches as well?

Comment: Got your point. Please, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use {powerjoin}

```r
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(
  df1, df2,
  by = ~ .x$x == .y$x | ! .x$x %in% .y$x & .x$x <= .y$x +.5 & .x$x >= .y$x -.5, 
  keep = "left")
#>      x   y
#> 1  4.8 6.6
#> 2 12.0 1.0
#> 3  4.0 1.0
#> 4  4.0 0.5
#> 5  3.5 0.5
#> 6 12.5 1.0
#> 7 12.5 1.8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I really like your solution, @moodymudskipper (+1)! And, Antoine, thanks for having co-created `powerjoin`!